# Trackpad Asus q200e

Tags: trackpad

I just bought an Asus q200e laptop, and the trackpad keeps having an issue where it stops being able to scrolls or use any other gestures.  Sometimes it works, other times it does not.

I already tried reinstalling the driver, but it says that it's already installed and can't continue.

Comment: Funny, I bought one too a while ago. As I recall, there were a few rounds of driver installations and many reboots before it finally worked the way I wanted it to. Good luck!

Comment: I've tried clicking on the "ASUS Live Update" icon, but it doesn't load anything either.  It's come up a few times asking me to restart, but so far it hasn't fixed the trackpad thing.  That normal?

Comment: See the answer here:  http://superuser.com/questions/527362/trackpad-gestures-on-asus-vivobook-stopped-working-after-using-mouse

Comment: This belongs on Superuser.